# Server not found problem

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, mozilla

I've encountered an problem, maybe trivial - when I try to load this page: http://home.thep.lu.se/~torbjorn/Pythia.html I recive classic 'Server not found' page. I'm using Mozilla Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04. Other pages (google.com, askubuntu.com etc.) work fine. Page that doesnt load on my laptop, works perfectly on other computers connected through same router. I've tried to connect via 3 different routers. Tried "sudo iptables -f" and "sudo ufw disable" commands. Also tried chromium browser. What may cause the problem?

Comment: Could you edit your question an add the output of `route -n` and `nslookup home.thep.lu.se` to it?

Answer (score 0):

You are on an LTS version of Ubuntu recommended for enterprise, for Home users I would recommend version 13.10 as it is the latest and most updated stable version of ubuntu.

Your problem may be that firefox is not updated (latest version is v26.0).

Try to install Midory and check if the problem is solved:

http://midori-browser.org/download/ubuntu/

it is based on Chrome and Safari, same webkit renderer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Midori doesn't solve the problem. I would like also avoid updating whole Ubuntu, because on a page doesn't load. I thought also it may be a problem with proxy, but I don't have any proxy set up..

Comment: Why not upgrade to the latest version? It is not only because a page isn't loading, it's because you will have the system updated to the latest stable version and all your apps and packages will be updated not only the OS, the newer the better, do you think programmers release new versions if they dont fix or optimize things? Take advantage of the hard work of many people, they have been working hard so that you can have less problems, have a more optimized OS and have better support.

Comment: Because of time, I have to spend on upgrading to 12.10, then to 13.04 and finally to 13.10. Also, there is possible data loss, so I have to backup all my files - another piece of time wasted. And do you really belive, that 12.04 is so special, that doesn't load this one specific page? Do you think this is best solution to my problem?
EDIT - Btw, on other computer with Ubuntu 12.04 this page loads, so it's not problem with version of OS

Comment: Problem solved by itself. Don't know how, but it did. Anyway - thank you for your replies, have a nice day :)